# MVC3 - add a folder to controllers?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to learn is it possible to add additional folder to `Controller` folder. My reason is pretty simple: I want to divide my project administration and client sides.

Example: I have a controller named `Post` that has actions `Index, Details, Delete, Create, Edit`. I want to make one controller as `user` controller that will consist of `Index, Details` and another controller as `admin` controller that will consist of `Delte, Create, Edit`. Then I will be able to easy distinguish what is what and put admin validation on whole admin class.

Another reason is that I want my url for administrating my site to look like `/admin/post/delete`, not `/post/delete`.

So is it possible, and if so then what would be the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sound like you want to use MVC Areas?  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b19d5a/areas-in-Asp-Net-mvc3/

Answer (score 2):

It's just a convention on placing controllers in **Controllers** folder.
Actually **MVC** finds controller in **current** loaded **assemblies**.
You can place them even in **other assemblies**.
So, fell free to create additional folders inside **Controllers**

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Ruby on Rails, yes, you can. In your routes files, config/routes.rb, add this:

```
 map.namespace :admin do |admin|
     admin.resources :posts
 end
```

Go to your terminal and navigate to your project, run rake routes. Now you get your posts controller under admin namespace... and your url will be:

```
.../admin/posts
```

Comment: Ruby is much like PHP, very easy to do these things there. Not so much in ASP.NET MVC3 though...